# Laravel ошибка Call to a member function first() on array

Tags: php, laravel

Laravel выводит ошибку которая четко говорит что *нельзя* вызывать **member** *функцию* `first()` *на массиве*.

Но Что значит **member function** ?

Где можно увидеть **список этих функций** ?

Answer (score -1):

Member function - функция объекта. Впрочем ошибка не про это, а про то что параметром у функции указан тип отличный от массива. Так что надо найти где она вызывается с неправильным параметром.